# Rails: how to rollback a botched migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rollback, rails-migrations

I'm an idiot...screwed up a migration in Rails:

thinking migrations would work like model generators (using `references:modelname`) I did the following:

```
$ rails g migration add_event_to_photos references:event
```

which created the migration

```
class AddEventToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :photos, :references, :event
  end
end
```

And now my development database (**SQLite3**) has a `references` column of type `event` in the `photos` table.

And my schema.rb has a line in the middle saying:

```
# Could not dump table "photos" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'event' for column 'references'
```

`rake db:rollback` is powerless against this:

```
$ rake db:rollback
==  AddEventToPhotos: reverting ===============================================
-- remove_column("photos", :references)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

So, how to roll back and maintain my development data in the database? I'd even be happy trashing the photos table if that's my only choice..but don't want to have to rebuild the whole thing. What to do?

---

btw- for anyone reading this about to make same stupid mistake...don't! Use the correct migration generator:

```
$ rails g migration add_event_to_photos event_id:integer
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way I found to do this was to recreate the table in the schema.rb file in `/db/`. Afterwards I ran a `rake db:reset` (if it says you have pending migrations, just delete them and try again).

This took care of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Go into the database by `./script/rails dbconsole`. Then type these commands:

```
.output dump.sql
.dump
```

In the file `dump.sql` you will have the SQL commands used to recreate and populate your database. Just edit it with your favourite editor (like `vim` ;-) removing or fixing the column type. You may also remove the invalid migration identifier from the `schema_migrations` table. Drop your database (I suggest just rename the `db/development.sqlite` file), create new database and read the dump file into it (using command `.read dump.sql`).

Now you just need to fix and run your migrations.

Answer (score 2):

add an empty down method and run rake db:rollback

edit ahh that's the new migration syntax, you can replace the body with simply:

```
def self.down; end
```

which is the old syntax, or perhaps delete the body altogether (haven't tried this) and then run `rake db:rollback`

Comment: This appears to move the rollback counter *(or whatever keeps track of migrations)* back ONE but it keeps the `references` column of type `event` in the database which prevents `schema.rb` from updating because it `Could not dump table "photos"...`

Comment: ah this is more complicated than I realized.  Can you simply delete the lines from schema.rb now that the schema number has rolled back?

Comment: yeah. but then, to my knowledge, I can't `rake db:schema:load` because the schema is all out of whack...

Comment: you could jump into sqlite and drop the photos table, then make a temporary migration which rebuilds the photos table and run that.  just copy the original photo table definition into a newly generated migration?

Comment: can't `drop` in SQLite3...that I know of anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, I know it's not SQLite specific you can revert to an older version schema perhaps, load it up. And try again from there? You can revert (checkout) specific files in GIT. And then do `def self.down; end`, as was suggested by another poster.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because while SQLite will create the schema with whatever type you give it (in this case `event` it can't dump that type back to ActiveRecord.

You need to edit the sqlite_master file and change create table string (`sql`) to be the right thing.

You probably want to back up your table first since messing up that string will wreck your table if you do it wrong.

[Here is a related rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2708#issuecomment-3343382)